# Spring Data Jpa + Spring Projections using @Query (native and JPQL) returns null for related entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-projections

What I'm trying to achieve is write the same query using 3 different approaches in Spring Data Jpa using JpaRepository interface:

1. Named Method Strategy.
2. @Query with JPQL.
3. @Query native SQL.

Here you can see how I've created Visit Entity with all relations which I'm trying to select.

```
public class Visit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    long visitId;
    LocalDateTime dateFrom;
    LocalDateTime dateTo;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    VisitStatus status;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    Doctor doctor;
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonManagedReference
    Patient patient;
    @ManyToMany
    @JsonManagedReference
    List<Disease> diseases;
    @ManyToMany
    @JsonManagedReference
    List<MedicalService> medicalServices;
    String mainSymptoms;
    String treatment;
    String allergy;
    String addiction;
    String comment;
```

I'm using Project Lombok to I wont copy all the annotations above the class.
So here is the experiment. I created method which should return all visits for specific doctor in given time interval.

Here is the method that I wrote:

```
List<VisitView> findByDoctorIdAndStatusAndDateFromGreaterThanEqualAndDateToLessThanEqual
            (long doctorId, VisitStatus visitStatus, LocalDateTime dateFrom, LocalDateTime dateTo);
```

As you can see I already implemented **VisitView** interface using **Spring Projections**.

Here it is:

```
public interface VisitView {
    long getDoctorId();
//    Doctor getDoctor();
//    interface Doctor {
//        String getFirstName();
//        String getLastName();
//    }
    String getDoctorFirstName();
    String getDoctorLastName();
    Long getPatientId();
    long getVisitId();
    LocalDateTime getDateFrom();
    LocalDateTime getDateTo();
    VisitStatus getStatus();
}
```

And using this method everything works just fine. I can get doctor firstName and lastName from Doctor Entity Class in both ways -> using getters and built in another Doctor interface to access fields from the Entity. Here you can see both JSON's using projected interface:

```
[
    {
        "status": "PAID",
        "visitId": 395,
        "dateTo": "2019-04-10T08:30:00",
        "dateFrom": "2019-04-10T08:00:00",
        "doctorId": 401,
        "patientId": 394,
        "doctorFirstName": "Aleksander",
        "doctorLastName": "Ziółko"
    }
]
```

```
[
    {
        "status": "PAID",
        "visitId": 395,
        "dateTo": "2019-04-10T08:30:00",
        "doctor": {
            "firstName": "Aleksander",
            "lastName": "Ziółko"
        },
        "dateFrom": "2019-04-10T08:00:00",
        "doctorId": 401,
        "patientId": 394
    }
]
```

Now I want to achieve the same result using @Query with JPQL and native SQL. So I printed out the generated SQL from this method i tried to use it with @Query annotation. Here you can see it:

@Query + native SQL:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT d.id as doctorId, d.firstName as firstName, d.lastName as lastName, p.id as patientId, v.id as visitId, v.dateFrom as dateFrom, v.dateTo as dateTo, v.status as status \n" +
            "FROM visit v \n" +
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN doctor d on v.doctor_id=d.id \n" +
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN users ud on d.id=ud.id \n" +
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN patient p on v.patient_id=p.id \n" +
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN users up on p.id=up.id \n" +
            "where d.id= :doctorId and v.status= :status and v.dateFrom>= :dateFrom and v.dateTo<= :dateTo ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<VisitView> searchForDoctorsVisitByStatusAndTimeIntervalNativeQuery(
            @Param("doctorId") long doctorId, @Param("status") String status, @Param("dateFrom") LocalDateTime dateFrom, @Param("dateTo") LocalDateTime dateTo);
```

@Query + JPQL:

```
@Query("SELECT d.id as doctorId, d.firstName as firstName, d.lastName as lastName, p.id as patientId, v.visitId as visitId, v.dateFrom as dateFrom, v.dateTo as dateTo, v.status as status \n" +
            "FROM Visit v \n" +
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN Doctor d ON v.doctor.id=d.id \n" +
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN Patient p ON v.patient.id=p.id \n" +
            "WHERE d.id= :doctorId AND v.status= :status AND v.dateFrom>= :dateFrom AND v.dateTo<= :dateTo")
    List<VisitView> searchForDoctorsVisitByStatusAndTimeIntervalJqplQuery(
            @Param("doctorId") long doctorId, @Param("status") VisitStatus status, @Param("dateFrom") LocalDateTime dateFrom, @Param("dateTo") LocalDateTime dateTo);
```

Both these queries return the JSONs with getters or Doctor interface with null values form **VisitView** :

```
[
    {
        "status": "PAID",
        "visitId": 395,
        "dateTo": "2019-04-10T08:30:00",
        "dateFrom": "2019-04-10T08:00:00",
        "doctorId": 401,
        "patientId": 394,
        "doctorFirstName": null,
        "doctorLastName": null
    }
]
```

```
[
    {
        "status": "PAID",
        "visitId": 395,
        "dateTo": "2019-04-10T08:30:00",
        "doctor": null,
        "dateFrom": "2019-04-10T08:00:00",
        "doctorId": 401,
        "patientId": 394
    }
]
```

What I've already done is tried many versions of Hibernate, because I read a lot about bugs which have appeared in different versions. Tried to group selected fields in alphabetically way, as i found this tip in another question here. Tried to use **@Join Column** annotation as it's suggested to do so but it did not help either.

And now I'm getting crazy because I can not figure out why it's not working.
Can somebody please help me?

Hibernate core verion -> 5.4.14.Final

Hibernate orm-search verion -> 5.11.5.Final

EDIT:
Issue above is solved but..
I have another question regarding this topic.

Entity Visit is in @ManyToMany relation with MedicalServices. Now i want to pull this list, so i projected another interface:

```
public interface VisitInfoWithPatientAndMedServices {
    LocalDateTime getDateFrom();
    LocalDateTime getDateTo();
    VisitStatus getStatus();
//  long getMedicalServicesId();
//  String getMedicalServicesService();
//  float getMedicalServicesPrice();
    List<MedicalService> getMedicalServices();
    interface MedicalService {
        String getId();
        String getService();
        float getPrice();
    }
}
```

This interface return only ONE object with List of MedicalServices using Named Method Strategy. Here is JSON from Postman:

```
[
    {
        "status": "PAID",
        "medicalServices": [
            {
                "id": "3",
                "service": "Something",
                "price": 250.0
            },
            {
                "id": "4",
                "service": "USG",
                "price": 400.0
            }
        ],
        "dateTo": "2019-04-10T08:30:00",
        "dateFrom": "2019-04-10T08:00:00"
    }
]
```

But i still can not get it right with the Native SQL and @Query annotation. I know that i can use solution from this question to get it, you can see it commented out in above VisitInfoWithPatientAndMedServices interface and its working but it's returning not 1 Visit Object with List of medical services, but 2 same object, each one with one medical services. It looks like this:

```
    {
        "dateTo": "2019-04-10T08:30:00",
        "dateFrom": "2019-04-10T08:00:00",
        "medicalServicesId": 3,
        "medicalServicesPrice": 250.0,
        "medicalServicesService": "Something",
        "status": "PAID"
    },
    {
        "dateTo": "2019-04-10T08:30:00",
        "dateFrom": "2019-04-10T08:00:00",
        "medicalServicesId": 4,
        "medicalServicesPrice": 400.0,
        "medicalServicesService": "USG",
        "status": "PAID"
    }
]
```

It's working just like in the Workbench, because I'm using MySQL.

Can i do anything about it to get the same JSON response using Named Method Strategy and @Query annotation (native SQL and JPQL) ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `d.firstName as firstName` and `d.lastName as lastName` this means you want to project the values in `firstName` and `lastName` field in interface.

Use `d.firstName as doctorFirstName, d.lastName as doctorLastName` in @Query to get the value.

```
 @Query("SELECT d.id as doctorId, d.firstName as doctorFirstName, d.lastName as doctorLastName, p.id as patientId, v.visitId as visitId, v.dateFrom as dateFrom, v.dateTo as dateTo, v.status as status \n" +
            "FROM Visit v \n" +
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN Doctor d ON v.doctor.id=d.id \n" +
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN Patient p ON v.patient.id=p.id \n" +
            "WHERE d.id= :doctorId AND v.status= :status AND v.dateFrom>= :dateFrom AND v.dateTo<= :dateTo")
    List<VisitView> searchForDoctorsVisitByStatusAndTimeIntervalJqplQuery(
            @Param("doctorId") long doctorId, @Param("status") VisitStatus status, @Param("dateFrom") LocalDateTime dateFrom, @Param("dateTo") LocalDateTime dateTo);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Yes i did try and it works fine.

Comment: Sure ! I voted too, but my reputation is to small to actually make it visible. Thank you once again.

Comment: I've edited the question, can you take a look one more time please?